# How to log spelling replacements in emacs?

Tags: emacs, ispell

I want to log to a file the ispell replacements that get made (whether manual `r`, or from a list `0`...)

Every time a "correction" is made, there are two words that are relevant:

1. The word that ispell identifies as incorrect.
2. The word that ends up in its place. [maybe `""` when its skipped]

I just want to log these pairs to a file for "analysis" (and possibly flashcards)

I am still browsing code to see if there is a place to wedge this in. I see `ispell-update-post-hook` used in `ispell-command-loop` but I'm not sure if that's what I want. I also am not sure how I'd both get the above pair of words and write them to a file, as the hook doesn't (elisp ignorance?) seem to provide access.

Comment: Store the file before and after the correction, check the `ediff` for the changes.

Comment: Thanks @choroba. I was hoping to not go outside of emacs. Also, the goal is to collect a long list of word pairs. I'd have to use `--word-diff` and a lot of fancy regex-ing in order to pop out the two words, isolated. I basically am just trying to automatically record my own spelling mistakes so I can LEARN (slept through fourth grade) to spell those thankfully few words correctly. I want a histogram of my spelling mistakes in other words. Paper and pen is an option, honestly.

Comment: You don't have to leave emacs. Store the contents before and after the correction in two buffers, then run `ediff-buffers`.

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you've requested.  It does not check for duplicates in the file that's generated, it simply appends to the existing file.

```
(defvar save-ispell-words-file "~/spell_check.txt")
(defadvice ispell-command-loop (after save-ispell-words activate)
  "Save the misspelled words and their replacements"
  (when (or (null ad-return-value)
            (stringp ad-return-value))
    (save-excursion
      (set-buffer (find-file-noselect save-ispell-words-file))
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert (format "%s %s\n" (ad-get-arg 2) (if (null ad-return-value) "\"\"" ad-return-value)))
      (save-buffer))))
```

Tested with Emacs 27.2.